# laravel fill selectbox with foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There are 3 tables

```
Sizes
id
name

Products
id
name

Product_sizes
id
product_id
size_id
```

I want to fill an selectbox with the id of product_sizes and the name of the foreign key connected table size.

for exampe:

```
product_sizes.id    1
sizes.name          medium
```

where medium would be found by size_id in product sizes.
How can I the name value in the list?

What i currently have

I can get the right row with

```
 $sizes =  $product->sizeAvailable()->lists('pr', 'size_id');
```

where sizeAvailable is a relation that returns all product_sizes for a selected product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need an `id` field in the pivot table because you can uniquely identify each row with the composite key `product_id, size_id`. A **Product** can belong to many **Sizes** and a **Size** can belong to many **Products**, thus you shouldn't have duplicate rows.

The relationships of each model are like the following:

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function sizeAvailable() {
        return $this->belongToMany('Size', 'product_sizes');
    }
}

class Size extends Model {
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongToMany('Product', 'product_sizes');
    }
}
```

Finally in your View you can use Blade functions to generate your selectbox:

```
<select>
    @foreach($product->sizeAvailable() as $size)
        <option value="{{ $size->id }}">{{ $size->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: The reason I use an id is because laravel needs one, when i delete a value it needs an id. Also it's much more efficient when passing only 1 value (the id) in stead of multiple values (combined key)  Thanks for the answer !

Comment: @SvenB What you are saying is true for standard tables, not for pivot tables. Check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) at the "Many to Many Relationships" section. You can use the `attach/detach/sync` methods to work on your pivot table by using only the `ids` of `Sizes` and `Products` tables.